# Syntax Error: Unexpected EOF While Parsing (Small Code)

Tags: python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxzug.jpg

My code. No errors show up on the editor.

```
def word_to_code(word):
#TODO1
myTranslatedWord = ""
for a in range(0, len(word)):
    for b in range(0, len(code)):
        if(word[a] == code[b]):
            myTranslatedWord += code[b]
print(myTranslatedWord)
return(myTranslatedWord)

code = {'A': '=.===',
        'B': '===.=.=.=',
        'C': '===.=.===.=',
        'D': '===.=.=',
        'E': '=',
        'F': '=.=.===.=',
        'G': '===.===.=',
        'H': '=.=.=.=',
        'I': '=.=',
        'J': '=.===.===.===',
        'K': '===.=.===',
        'L':  '=.===.=.=',
        'M': '===.===',
        'N': '===.=',
        'O': '===.===.===',
        'P': '=.===.===.=',
        'Q': '===.===.=.===',
        'R': '=.===.=',
        'S': '=.=.=',
        'T': '===',
        'U': '=.=.===',
        'V': '=.=.=.===',
        'W': '=.===.===',
        'X': '===.=.=.=.===',
        'Y': '===.=.===.===',
        'Z': '===.====.=.='}

print((word_to_code("PAPI"))
```

This is for a class where I'm trying to independently problem solve an objective. For some reason though my code is not working.

Comment: Can you fix indentation ?

Comment: looks like indentation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many parentheses in the last line. It should be

```
print(word_to_code("PAPI"))
```

In the future, copy the actual text of the error into the question instead of as a picture.

---

Note that there's also a fairly large problem with how you do the translation. Remember what dictionaries are good for - you should be able to write that function with only a single loop.

Comment: Much Thanks. The error is fixed but a new one popped up ]now. I'm fairly new, and I've gone to tutorialspoint for dictionaries, but was wondering if you had any other recommendations to look at?

Comment: Not in particular - there's lot of good information out there, and I don't think I've heard anything bad about that one.